# matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0 with 2 degree

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
import numpy as np
x_train = [[1,7978], [1,7968], [1,797], [1,798], [1,7978]]
y_train = [[5],[5],[5],[6],[5]]
x_test = [[1,7978], [1,7964], [1,7946], [1,7968], [1,7978]]
y_test = [[5],[5],[7],[7],[5]]

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)

xx = np.linspace(0, 26, 100)
yy = regressor.predict(xx.reshape(xx.shape[0], 1))
plt.plot(xx, yy)

quadratic_featurizer = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
x_train_quadratic = quadratic_featurizer.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_quadratic = quadratic_featurizer.transform(x_test)
```

=========================================================================

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9e046a813015> in <module>()
     11 
     12 xx = np.linspace(0, 26, 100)
---> 13 yy = regressor.predict(xx.reshape(xx.shape[0], 1))
     14 plt.plot(xx, yy)
     15 

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

I have tried to change the size of the column but it still can't run and have imported matplot and sklearn

Comment: Is that the full traceback?  It's hard to tell what arrays are involved in the `matmul` (some where deep in `predict`?),  `np.ones((3,1))@np.ones((2,4))` reproduces your error message.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?